# Extracting code from onCreate cause resource to return null

Tags: android, android-activity, android-resources, android-lifecycle

**Back Story**

I am setting a background programmatically so I do the following in `onCreate`, and it works fine.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dogs);
    Drawable bkg = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.bg2);
    bkg.setAlpha(50);
    findViewById(R.id.bkg).setBackgroundDrawable(bkg);
    ...
}
```

**Problem**

Needing to repeat the same process for multiple activities, I decide to extract the code into a helper class call MyVars and inside MyVars I have

```
private static Drawable bkg = null;

public static void setPageBackground(Context context, View view) {
    if (null == bkg) {
        Drawable bkg = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.bg2);
        bkg.setAlpha(50);
    }
    view.setBackgroundDrawable(bkg);
}
```

Then inside `onCreate` I now have

```
MyVars.setPageBackground(this, findViewById(R.id.bkg));
```

but then `bkg` is always null, which means `context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.bg2);` always returns null. Does anyone understand why? By the way, I run the debugger and indeed the resource always returns null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bkg is always null because you assign the drawable to a method field bkg not to the class field bkg:

Change your method to this

```
public static void setPageBackground(Context context, View view) {
    if (null == bkg) {
        //Drawable bkg = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.bg2);

        //use class field bkg
        bkg = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.bg2);
        bkg.setAlpha(50);
    }
    view.setBackgroundDrawable(bkg);
}
```